# Conditional Rails form using <SELECT>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what I know is probably an inefficient way of doing this, but I want to make it work first before trying to optimize it. Essentially, there are few things that I want the code to do that aren't working right now:

- The placeholders appear in the snippet below, but do not seem to appear in any web browser..
- The first dropdown does not seem to display any of the options
- Upon selection of the second dropdown (country), another question should appear asking the user to select from a more specific region (municipal, etc.)

Any help or direction is appreciated.

```html
 


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/application-258e88d.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload">
<script src="/application-cbd3cd4.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
<script>

var data = {
  countries: [{
    name: 'China',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Beijing',
      childs: [{name: 'Beijing'}]
  }] 

  }, {
    name: 'India',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Uttar',
      childs: [{name: 'Kanpur'}, {name: 'Ghaziabad'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Maharashtra',
      childs: [{name: 'Mumbai'}, {name: 'Pune'}]
    }]

  }, {
    name: 'USA',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Alabama'}]
  }]
};

function buildSelect(name, data, childs) {
  var div = $('<div>');
  div.addClass('hidden autoSelect ' + data.name + ' ' + name);
  var label = $('<label>');
  label.text(name);
  var select = $('<select>');
  var option = $('<option>');
  option.text('--');
  select.append(option);
  data.childs.forEach(function (child) {
     option = $('<option>');
     option.val(child.name);
     option.text(child.name);
     select.append(option);
  });
  if (childs) select.on('change', updateCities);
  label.append(select);
  div.append(label);
  $('.country').append(div);
}

function buildForms(data) {
  data.countries.forEach(function (country) {
     buildSelect('State', country, true);
     country.childs.forEach(function (state) {
       buildSelect('City', state);
     });
  });
}

function hideAutoSelect (name) {
  $('div.autoSelect.'+name).addClass('hidden');
}

function updateStates() {
  var v = this.value;
  if (v) {
    hideAutoSelect('State');
    hideAutoSelect('City');
    var div = $('div.autoSelect.'+v);
    div.removeClass('hidden');
    var select = $('select', div);
    if (select.val()) $('div.autoSelect.'+select.val()).removeClass('hidden');
  }
}

function updateCities() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  if (v) {
    hideAutoSelect('City');
    $('div.autoSelect.'+v).removeClass('hidden');
  }
}

$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function () {
  buildForms(data);
  $('[name=country]').on('change', updateStates);
})

</script>
</head>
<body>
   
  <div class="container">
      <h3>Add Vendor</h3>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <form action="/add/vendors" method="post">
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>Create vendor ID<span class="req">*</span>
                <input placeholder="V00000">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>Vendor name<span class="req">*</span>
                <input placeholder="John">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>Vendor type<span class= "req">*</span>
              <select>
                <option selected="--">--</option>
                <option value= "Option 1"></option>
                <option value= "Option 2"></option>
                <option value= "Option 3"></option>
              </select></label>
          </div>             
          <div class="field-wrap country">         
            <label>Vendor origin<span class="req">*</span>
              <select name="country">
                <option selected= "--">--</option>
                <option value= "China" >China</option>
                <option value= "India" >India</option>
                <option value= "USA"  >USA</option>
              </select>
            </label>
         </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to reduce your question content to your immediate problem if possible. Do not post the whole HTML page. Include the relevant parts only and add the detailed steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I cut down the code. Thanks for the suggestion